# Need to check if $H\triangleleft G$ in a covering of the Klein bottle

Tags: group-theory, covering-spaces

> Let $G=\mathbb Z\rtimes\mathbb Z$ and $H=\mathbb Z\rtimes7\mathbb Z$. I want to check if $H◁G$.

I know I need to calculate $N_G(H)$, and I think this is
$$N_G(H)=\{(m,n) ∈ G \mid (m,n)(l,7k)(m,n)^{-1} ∈ H,  \forall l,k\}$$

but I'm not sure when to go from there. I wasn't given great notes for this.

I think I can use
$$(m,n)(l,7k)(m,n)^{-1}=(m+(-1)^ml, n+7k)(-(-1)^nm,-n)
=(m+(-1)^nl+(-1)^n+7k)(-1)^(n+1)m,7k)
=(m(1-(-1)^k)+(-1)^nl,7k)$$

But what does this mean? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You may consult the on-site [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for help on proper formatting.

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$? I guess the second one?

Comment: The second one!

Comment: Subgroups of abelian groups are all normal.

Comment: Oh, I see, $G$ is $\Bbb Z$ semidirect product $\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. Then you should edit that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better not to make those calculations (although they certainly give you the result eventually). Because $G$ is semi-direct product $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ you can take $\pi$ the projection of $G$ onto the second factor this gives you :

$$\pi: \mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $$

$$(a,b)\mapsto b$$

Now this is a surjective group morphism and from the very definition of $H$ you have that $\pi^{-1}(7\mathbb{Z})=:H$. It is clear that $7\mathbb{Z}\triangleleft \mathbb{Z}$, then you can use the following fact (easy exercise) the inverse image of a normal subgroup by a surjective morphism is a normal subgroup. Hence $H\triangleleft G$.